# Play Json - custom JsResultException

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to parse a json with Play Json, using `as` to parse single "fields". Like this:

`val data = (json \ "dataField").as[String]`

This throws a JsResultException if unable to parse the field or invalid. However, as I need to output the error in a "freindlier" way, I need to set a custom JsResultException message.

Is there a way of achieving this? I could do something like:

`(json \ "dataField").asOpt[String].getOrElse(throw new Exception("Error parsing dataField field."))` and then matching Some(data: String)... None... but it seems too much code for each field I need to parse.

Comment: Rather use `.validate` and compose `JsResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `validate` you get a list of errors.

```
json.validate[MyClass] match {
  case JsSuccess(myClass, _) =>
    // do something
  case JsError(errors) =>
    // do something with the errors
}
```

The errors are of type `Seq[(JsPath, Seq[JsonValidationError])]`.
You can transform this to whatever you want.